# Navbar Alignment with bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, navbar, nav

I have a basic layout that I'm trying to achieve. I have a .container class with a logo floated to the left, and then i want a bootstrap navbar floated to the right and also on the top of the container, and it seems to be floating correctly with the "pull-right" class on the "navbar-nav" class with bootstrap, but it is underneath the brand logo and I cannot for the life of me figure out why or how to get it aligned correctly.

Anyways, Heres the html....

```
<html lang= "en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class= "container">
        <header class = "headerWrap">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class ="brand"></div>
                    <div class = " userNav col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4">
                        <nav class = "navbar navbar-default">
                            <ul class= "nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                                <li><a href= "#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href= "#">Contact Us</a></li>
                                <li><a href= "#">Sign In</a></li>
                                <li><a href= "#">Cart</a></li>
                                <li><a href= "#">Location + Directions</a></li>
                                <li><a href= "#">Who We Are</a></li>
                                <li><a href= "#">Alumni Network</a></li>    
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
            </div>

        </header>

    </div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Heres the CSS:

```
$font-color: white;

body {
    background-color: black;
}

.headerWrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}

.brand {
    background-image:url(img/Screen%20Shot%202015-10-25%20at%2010.13.40%20PM.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
}

.userNav {
    float: right;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a{
    color: $font-color;
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just because you have added `col-sm-offset-4` class to your `userNav` element. Remove it, everything will work as expected. When you keep `col-sm-offset-4` class what happens is, it treats that the `element` needs `12` grids totally. Since it has been already moved 4 grids by `brand - logo`, and framework cannot assign `12` grids in the same `row`, it moves it to new `row`. So no need to give `offset` again. Just change the element's class as below:

```
<div class ="userNav col-sm-8"> <!--remove col-sm-offset-4 from here-->
```

Just a **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/eh1evozn/)** for you

Comment: Ah, I knew it was something simple. For some reason I wasn't thinking of it as an element with its own margins and padding and all of that. Thanks a lot for your help.